# How to access angular bootstrap UI from controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use angularJS bootstrap tabset, in my requirement, I need to add a next button to let customer to switch tabs.
Here is my code:

```
<div ng-controller='ctr'>
  <tabset>
  <tab  active='sqTab' heading="tab1">
       tabt 1     
  </tab>
  <tab  active='psTab' heading="tab2">
       tabt 2    
  </tab>
  </tabset>
  <button click='next()')>next</button>
</div>
```

In the controller "ctr":

```
$scope.sqTab = true;
$scope.psTab = false;
$scope.next = function(){
 $scope.sqTab = false;
 $scope.psTab = true;
}
```

As you can see, I set active for each tab, it works fine when the page load,I can switch to tab2 after I hit next, but if I click tab head to switch back, and try to hit next button again, it didn't work,it may be the reason the directive is isolated scope, I can't access it's active, but if so why I can switch first time? Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: What do you mean by clicking on tab head? Can you please specify? Does it mean that your tabt1 and tabt 2 themselves are buttons that should perform switching action on clicking them?

Comment: everything is normal, I just add a next button to let customer to switch from tab1 to tab2, tab-head is title,which we usually use to switch the tabs.

Comment: The [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) actually have an example of programatically setting the active tab. It uses an `index` on the tabs and the `active` attribute is on the `<tabset>` element. Have you tried doing it that way?

Comment: yes,the active could be index or string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't use the AngularJS-UI bootstrap directives. Here is a working sample based on what you have.

*Javascript*

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.activeTab = "sqTab";
        $scope.next = function() {
            $scope.activeTab = "psTab";
        }
    });
```

*HTML*

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <form class="tab-form-demo">
        <uib-tabset active="activeTab">
            <uib-tab index="'sqTab'" heading="tab1">
                Here is some content on Tab 1
            </uib-tab>
            <uib-tab index="'psTab'" heading="tab2">
                Here is some different content on Tab 2
            </uib-tab>
        </uib-tabset>
        <button ng-click="next()">next</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Notice that when using a string index you have to put quotes around it. Also notice that the `uib-` version of all the bootstrap elements need to be used. Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dadv8a1p/) using the above code.

Comment: Thanks dude, this is what I want:)

Answer (score 0):

Use a scope variable to enumerate through the tab indexes with a next and perhaps previous button.

**HTML**

```
  <button ng-click="previous()" ng-disabled="activeTab===0">Previous</button>
  <button ng-click="next()" ng-disabled="activeTab===1">Next</button>
  <div>
    <uib-tabset active="activeTab">
      <uib-tab index="0" heading="Tab 0">
        <div>This is tab 0</div>
      </uib-tab>
      <uib-tab index="1" heading="Tab 1">
        <div>This is tab 1</div>
      </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
  </div>
```

**Controller**

```
  $scope.activeTab = 0;

  $scope.next = function() {
    $scope.activeTab += 1;
  };
  $scope.previous = function() {
    $scope.activeTab -= 1;
  };
```

Here's a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/K4fCdRc7wc5B38Lm9lkx?p=preview).